# Can I define a custom compare function for redis zset?

Tags: redis

Background:

I'm now using php+redis as my backend to store a rank.
And zset seems to be a good solution to handle this.
However the rank contains multiple scores, if the first score equals, I need to compare the second score to decide the ordering. There are 3 scores in total.

I thought there will be an interface that I can set a custom compare function for a specific zset so that I can do the sort job inside it but I failed to find it. Besides, I'd like the rank to be sorted when it's added. if I need to sort again everytime there is a request to get the rank, then this is wasteful I think.

expect result:

```
zadd myset 1000_100_3000 matchId1
zadd myset 1000_2500_250 matchId2
zadd myset 1000_2500_200 matchId3
```

`zrange myset 0 -1` returns:

```
matchId2
matchId3
matchId1
```

something like this

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: no, you can't do that

However, you can often compose multiple keys in such a way to make them sortable. In your case, an obvious candidate would be to determine the max range of the three pieces, and just compose them all into a single big number. For example, 1000_100_3000 could perhaps be the number 100001003000 (4 decimal digits per chunk), which can be trivially compared or decomposed. You might also want to think in terms of bits rather than digits, though. For example, maybe allow 20 bits per segment, and use shift/mask bit operations to compose/decompose (i.e. `(1000 << 40) | (100 << 20) | (3000)`)

Comment: That's a beautiful/advanced/pro tip :)

Comment: @ItamarHaber I went on a binge a while ago looking at binary sortable composite key algos; it was fun, especially when looking at things like making floating point binary sortable. Fun times.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, your first solution is my current solution, but I'm not sure if the max int in redis can handle this if the three scores growing. Using bits can be better.